# I am trying to deploy a Nextjs to cloud function. ```iron-session/next``` returns ```undefined``` on Google Cloud Function. How do i fix this resolve?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-cloud-functions

Everything works fine on my local environment and also on Vercel but i wish to deploy the nextjs application to run on cloud function and this is where things got weird.

Here is my nextjs application sample code.

/api/auth/signin.ts API route handler function

```
import { ClientError, gql, GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request'
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { withSessionRoute } from '../../../lib/session'
import nc from 'next-connect';

const handler = nc<NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse>({
  onNoMatch: (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) =>
    res.status(404).send("Not found " + res.status),
}).post(withSessionRoute(loginHandler))
// const handler = withSessionRoute(loginHandler)
const { GRAPHQL_BASE_URL } = process.env

const client = new GraphQLClient(GRAPHQL_BASE_URL!)

const loginMutation = gql`
  mutation requestLogin($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(authLoginInput: { email: $email, password: $password }) {
      access_token
      refresh_token
    }
  }
`

async function loginHandler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
): Promise<any> {
  const { email, password } = req.body as any
  console.log('login request body: ', req.body)

  if (!email || !password) {
    res.status(400).end()
    return
  }

  try {
    const getUserResponse = await client.request(loginMutation, {
      email,
      password,
    })

    const { login } = getUserResponse
    console.log('login response', login)
    if (!login) {
      res.status(403).end('Invalid login')
      return
    }
    console.log('response login', login)
    const { access_token, refresh_token } = login

    ;(req.session as any).user = {
      access_token,
      refresh_token,
    }

    await req.session.save()
    console.log('user ssession', (req.session as any).user)
    res.status(200).json({ access_token, refresh_token })
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof ClientError) {
      return res
        .status(503)
        .json({ msg: (error.response as any) })
    }
    console.log('error', (error as ClientError).message)
    res.status(500).json({ msg: error })
  }
}

export default handler;
```

/api/user/me.ts

The app returns a jwt token both on local dev and vercel but `undefined` on Cloud Functions.

```
const handler = nc<NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse>({
  onNoMatch: (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) =>
    res.status(404).send("Not found " + res.status),
}).get(
  withSessionRoute(async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const defaultReturnObject = {
      authenticated: false,
      user: null,
      message: "",
    };
    const token = (req.session as any).user?.access_token ?? req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
 console.log('token from ME', token)

    try {
      client.setHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
      const getUserResponse = await client.request(getUserProfileQuery);
      const { profile } = getUserResponse;
      // console.log('profile', profile)
      if (!profile) {
        res.status(401).json(defaultReturnObject);
        return;
      }
      res.status(200).json({ authenticated: true, user: profile });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      res
        .status(403)
        .json({ ...defaultReturnObject, msg: (error as any).message });
    }
  })
);
export default handler;
```

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const { https } = require('firebase-functions')
const { default: next } = require('next')
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')

admin.initializeApp()
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({
  dev,
  // the absolute directory from the package.json file that initialises this module
  // IE: the absolute path from the root of the Cloud Function
  conf: {
    distDir: 'build',
    // reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
      dangerouslyAllowSVG: true,
      contentSecurityPolicy: "default-src 'self'; script-src 'none'; sandbox;",
      domains: ['firebasestorage.googleapis.com', 'images.unsplash.com'],
    },
  },
})

const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
exports.nextMerchantServer = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private');
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)

    return handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
});
```

Do i need to enable anything on Function to allow cookie session to work?

Thank you guys, i really need all the help i can get.

Comment: did you solve this ? i think it has something to do with NextApiRequest